# Why can't a hopper deposit into Large Chests?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone, minecraft-hypixel-skyblock

I'm playing on Minecraft Hypixel Skyblock, and I'm having trouble with a redstone system I'm making.

It seems to me that hoppers are not depositing their items into Large Chests (two-wide). They only are able to deposit their items into normal chests (one-wide).

Is this a bug? How do I fix it?

Comment: I have tried to replace all chest and hopper,but it still doesn’t work for big chest

Answer (score 3):

It's a Hypixel quirk. Hypixel is highly "optimized" to handle a large number of players. A lot of the optimizations severely break the redstone system. The only way to "fix" it is not to play on Hypixel.